# Is there a better way to dynamically add css in razor than with @if()

Tags: css, optimization, razor

Can I optimize the class assignment here at all? I have to do this in a lot of different places and am trying to figure out how to make it less...copy paste-ish / inline.

```
@foreach(var m in Model.ObjectList)
{
 <td @if(m.RandomObject.isFlagged){
     <text>class="flagged"</text>
     }
 >
  @m.RandomObject.Name @m.RandomObject.Description
 </td>
}
```

Note that each ObjectList in the different places has differnt RandomObjects.

I suppose this would work too, but still seems not best practice:

```
<td class="flagged@(m.RandomObject.isFlagged)">...
```

and then have the css definition be `.flaggedtrue`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use the `?` [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this kind of thing

```
<td class="@(m.RandomObject.isFlagged ? "flagged" : "")">
  ...
</td>
```

Comment: While nice to read :), I was hoping for a more generic approach in order to avoid marking every td that contains a RandomObject with a conditional

Comment: @TravisJ: there's no way around the logic; +1 for Andrew's tidy answer. Could be abstracted into a helper method for extra "neatness"

Comment: I think I understand, so instead of checking the conditional for each `td`, the alternative is your second suggestion - i.e. to output the conditional itself and create css classes that include it: `<td class="flagged-@(m.RandomObject.isFlagged)">`  would result in `.flagged-true` and `.flagged-false` css classes

Comment: @Andrew - Either one of those options I proposed seem to me to be too inline and mixing the view with some logic. I was hoping to separate out the logic somehow back into a helper or something along those lines. Maybe an inclusion in the view model. Maybe with some jQuery or javascript once the view is built. I am not sure how others have accomplished this and was unable to find a good example searching so I asked this question. Sorry if it was too vague, but I was not sure how else to phrase it.

Comment: @TravisJ - in that case, I'd use a [Razor helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) that takes the `RandomObject` as a parameter to keep the main part of the document clean.  However, in the helper, I think I'd still go with the `?` ternary operator to insert the css classes